# TypeScript - Resolving Modules Without 3rd Party Tools

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to transpile my TypeScript modules into a single ES5 file and resolve the modules without using a 3rd party tool like WebPack or SystemJS?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "--outFile" directive of the typescript compiler, that might be what you're looking for.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: That handles the combining them into a single file, but doesn't resolve the modules, unless I'm missing something.